# Adding component to page when more specific route is used

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What I'm trying to do is to display User details next to the table of users.

The user table is displayed on `/users` route and when I go to `/users/0` I want to display both, the user table, and component `User` with the user's details.

Here is what I tried to do: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-redirects-typescript-fg8yf

This, however, displays only a blank page when I try to navigate to the user's details.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided `exact` prop here,

```
<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
```

When you provide `exact` prop, it will only match the path `/users` and not anything else. So when you give path `/users/0` it will not navigate, because there is no matching `Route` present.

You need to remove the `exact` prop,

```
<Route path="/users" component={Users} />
```

Read more about [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop.

Comment: there were multiple errors in my code but this was indeed the solution for the specific problem I was asking about